# Nebula Graph fails on CentOS 6.5

Tags: centos6.5, nebula-graph

Nebula Graph fails on CentOS 6.5, the error message is as follows:

```sh
# storage log
Heartbeat failed, status:RPC failure in MetaClient: N6apache6thrift9transport19TTransportExceptionE: AsyncSocketException: connect failed, type = Socket not open, errno = 111 (Connection refused): Connection refused

# meta log
Log line format: [IWEF]mmdd hh:mm:ss.uuuuuu threadid file:line] msg
E0415 22:32:38.944437 15532 AsyncServerSocket.cpp:762] failed to set SO_REUSEPORT on async server socket Protocol not available
E0415 22:32:38.945001 15510 ThriftServer.cpp:440] Got an exception while setting up the server: 92failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:0: Protocol not available
E0415 22:32:38.945057 15510 RaftexService.cpp:90] Setup the Raftex Service failed, error: 92failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:0: Protocol not available
E0415 22:32:38.949586 15463 NebulaStore.cpp:47] Start the raft service failed
E0415 22:32:38.949597 15463 MetaDaemon.cpp:88] Nebula store init failed
E0415 22:32:38.949796 15463 MetaDaemon.cpp:215] Init kv failed!
```

Nebula service status is as follows:

```sh
[root@redhat6 scripts]# ./nebula.service status  all
[WARN] The maximum files allowed to open might be too few: 1024
[INFO] nebula-metad: Exited
[INFO] nebula-graphd: Exited
[INFO] nebula-storaged: Running as 15547, Listening on 44500
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason for error: CentOS 6.5 system kernel version is 2.6.32, which is less than 3.9. However, SO_REUSEPORT only supports Linux 3.9 and above.

Upgrading the system to CentOS 7.5 can solve the problem by itself.